# save excel files to subfolders according to their name

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro which reads some CSV files and creates excel files from those. Then it save the created files in the same folder as CSV files exist. I need to create sub folders which groups the excel files according to part of their names and save the excel files in those sub folders: 
Example:

```
IM_26451405_abc_FUM_20.09.2016.xls
IM_26451405_gdd_FUM_20.09.2016.xls
```

should be saved in a sub folder with the name: `26451405` and

```
IM_26451234_abc_FUM_20.09.2016.xls
IM_26451234_gdd_FUM_20.09.2016.xls
IM_26451234_wer_FUM_20.09.2016.xls
```

should be saved in a sub folder with the name: `26451234` and so on...

here is the Sub for that part.

```
Public Sub StartProcessing()
Dim formatName As String
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim lastSheet As Worksheet
Dim destFileName As String
Dim flagGotDestName As Boolean
Dim destWorkbook As Workbook

Set csvProcessor = Me

   For Each file In csvProcessor.getFiles

flagGotDestName = False
Set destWorkbook = Nothing
Set currentSheet = Nothing


For Each cell In file

    fileName = cell.Text
    sheetName = cell.Offset(0, 1).Text
    formatName = cell.Offset(0, 2).Text

    Set currentSheet = getWorksheetFromCSV(sheetName, fileName)


    If Not flagGotDestName Then
        destFileName = Left(fileName, InStrRev(fileName, "_", , vbTextCompare)) & "FUM_" & format(Now(), "dd.mm.yyyy") & ".xls"
        destFileName = Left(destFileName, InStrRev(destFileName, "\", , vbTextCompare)) & "FM_" & Right(destFileName, Len(destFileName) - InStrRev(destFileName, "\", , vbTextCompare))
        flagGotDestName = True
        currentSheet.Move
        Set destWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    End If

    With destWorkbook
        Set currentSheet = .Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    End With

    formatSheet currentSheet, formatName
    Set lastSheet = currentSheet
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
destWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=destFileName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges

destWorkbook.Close

Err.Clear
On Error GoTo 0
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is the problem with that macro, does it fail or what is the issue?

Comment: No, it just save all excels in one folder and dose not make sub foldersq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example solution:

```
[...]

mainPath = "C:\Users\RandomGuy\Workspace\"
fileName = "IM_26451405_abc_FUM_20.09.2016.xls"
subDrectoryName = Mid(fileName, 4, 8)
filePath = mainPath & subDirectoryName & "\"

If Dir(filePath) <> "" Then
    MkDir filePath
End If

destWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False, ConflictResolution:=xlLocalSessionChanges
```

So, what you need is to find this `mainPath` that is directory, where your CSV files are stored. I don't know if this is always same directory, or it is dynamic based on cell value. Then extract folder name form file name and check if this folder already exists. If not, create one and save file in it.